# Does 4th gen iPod Shuffle comes with iPhone earphone that has mic and volume buttons?

Tags: ipod, ear-phones

My iPhone earphone went bad today. I need an iPod shuffle too for jogging, so I wanted to buy one. I'm wondering if it actually comes with the same earphone as the one that iPhone comes with?

Bonus: What does this mean:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It certainly does't come with the same ones at the iPhone, which are characterised by the 3 button inline controls & mic

Checking with a touch I bought recently, it seems it came with just plain old earphones.

Previous models of the shuffle had the full inline controls on the headphones, but this was due to the lack of controls on the actual device.  They took some stick for that decision, and since reverting to the old shape they no longer do this, and as such I think they have also reverted to using standard headphones.

As for your picture, I think it means that the headphone connector, unlike on the iPhone/iPod touches/Airs etc, is a normal 3.5mm headphone only adapter, without the extra internal pinout to support a mic.  The mic is now actually located on the shuffle itself, thus not requiring you to need a headset to use the voiceover functions - check the tiny hole next to the headphone socket:

[image]

So it means that while the headphones will still work if you use iPhone headphones, or any of the other headset style ones with inline controls, the mic will not be used, and the one on the device will always be used, although it seems the remote functions for volume and next/back might be available.

Comment: The tiny hole next to the headphone socket is indicator light. Search for word 'mic' in iPod shuffle manual  finds only that external microphone isn't supported.

Comment: Just to confirm your guess in the last paragraph: According to [these](http://support.apple.com/kb/SP592) [two](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3458?viewlocale=en_US) documents you can use headphones with a remote. The mic will not work. The volume buttons and center button will work.